# Visual Studio Opens Additional Split Window When Ctrl+Click on class

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I ctrl+click on a class (such as UserEnabledController in this picture) to view the implementation it navigates me to the implementation in a non split maximized window as usual, but when I navigate back to this AccountController there is an annoying split screen that is sort of previewing the UserEnabledController. How do I turn this setting off? I am on Visual Studio 2017 professional as a fresh install with the latest version of Resharper 2018.1 Ultimate.

[image]

Comment: Off topic as its not actually code related

Comment: Where should I post

Comment: Tools, Options & search for "Peek"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools, options, & search for "Peek" disable "Control click shows definitions in Peek"

[image]